# INACTIVE task - how to kill them

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

When I create a new revision of my tasks in aws ecs, ecs creates two new instances as requested.

However, it leaves the other two untouched:

[image]

AWS does know, however that this is not correct:

[image]

Why is it like that?

I have a minimum health of 100% (two tasks) and a max of 200%.

My understanding is that it starts two new tasks and then kills the inactive ones. But the inactive ones just stay there forever (until I manually kill them), doing unpredicable things on old code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note that it isn't the old *tasks*, but the old *task-definition* that is inactive. You have two running tasks that are using taskdef:34 and 2 older ones that are using an older, now inactive taskdef.

ECS/ALB does stop routing new requests to the old tasks immediately, but they will stay around as long as there are active connections to them. This is really a mechanism to enable zero-downtime graceful switchover. If your app keep long lived connections, or that is the nature of your transactions, your old tasks will stick around for longer.

You can, if you so desire, select the old tasks and terminate them manually and immediately; or even write up a script to terminate all tasks running on older taskdefs. Needless to say, this can be disruptive to active connections/transactions.

Comment: That makes a whole lot of sense. So once there are no connections, aws would shut it down? There are no long running connections from outside. However, would this apply for connections between task definitions? This task consists of an nginx / java app and the nginx maintains a connection to the upstream java task.

Comment: Can't speak to the exact internal implementation of when ECS decides it is safe to terminate a task, documentation says "waits for the connections to drain". If you don't believe your Application is causing them to stay alive, you should reach out to support for them to investigate. That said, "wait for connections to drain" does sound like it would include inter-task connections.

Comment: I'm facing a similar problem. Have you found a better way to handle this?

Comment: Seems to me that the best thing would be to incorporate logic into the container that checks to see if the task definition that started the container is "inactive."  If it is, the appropriate action is taken.   I'm currently looking for/writing python code that does this.